# How can I retrieve my own iOS app battery consumption programmatically?

Tags: ios, ios8, battery, batterylevel, consumption

Is there a public API that I can use to retrieve my own app battery consumption directly in the code like iOS is giving in settings app ?

Example of what Apple can provide through settings :
http://img.wonderhowto.com/img/63/90/63537324981100/0/view-battery-usage-stats-for-individual-apps-your-iphone-ios-8.w654.jpg

If not, how can I track in an easy way the battery usage of my app ? Is there any private APIs for that ?

Thank you for you help !

Comment: have you find any solution?

Comment: @Sulabh Not at all :-( Sorry !